# Increase the tags beyond 5 for experience on Careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, cv, experience

Example, if you had a job writing J2EE apps then it's quite likely all these tags will apply:

- java
- j2ee
- spring
- hibernate, eclipselink, openjpa, etc
- jpa
- ejb
- spring-mvc, seam, struts or something similar
- servlets
- jsp
- html
- css
- javascript
- jquery
- ant or maven
- oracle, mysql, etc

And that's before you even use anything nonstandard and noteworthy.

Answer (score 1):

we now allow 10 tags on job and education sections.